# Get value of array input on js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

Hello guys i have a problem, im trying to get with js the value of an input that contains an array but i dont have succes on it.

This is mi input:

```
<input name="mail_2[]"  id="mail_2" class="styled" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $f[llave] ?>">
```

And im trying to get the value like this (Does not work);

```
mail_2 = document.mailing.mail_2.value;
```

Also i try this, but when i send to php, it seems nothing is on the variable:

```
mail_2 = document.mailing.elements["mail_2[]"];
```

Can someone help me with this one please.

Comment: *"but when i send to php"* `mail_2 = document.mailing.elements["mail_2[]"];` that's JS and not PHP.

Comment: i send the form via ajax, what im trying to do, is save the input value with js, that way i cand send it to php

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('mail_2[]')
    var checkeds = [];
for(key in elements){

    if(elements[key].checked){
        checkeds.push(elements[key].value);
    }
}
    console.log(checkeds)
```

Comment: I try it but at the end i just want to send the value to php, and the problem continues, php is not detecting the value